# Flutter no backbutton on topleft, when calling a listviewScreen from a drawer

Tags: flutter

im new to Flutter. I have a mainpage, which is a listview with a drawer. I manage to call a second listview, which is mainly a copy of the mainpage without the drawer. But on the secondpage i see no backbutton on the top left.

Here i call the secondpage inside the drawer:

```
                  onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new  ListViewTeam()),
                );
              },
```

and my secondpage begins with this code:

```
  @override
  _ListViewTeamState createState() => new _ListViewTeamState();
}

class _ListViewTeamState extends State<ListViewTeam> {
  List<Team> items = new List();
  DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    db.getAllTeams().then((teams) {
      setState(() {
        teams.forEach((team) {
          items.add(Team.fromMap(team));
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Teams',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Teams'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        ),

        body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
```

Hope someone can help a noob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the Below code replace this code at your second page I hope this will work for you

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Teams'),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
    ),

    body: Center(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
```